# Is there a powerful image file manipulation app with a standard GUI?

Tags: scanner, gimp

Several times a year, I scan a document which doesn't fit in my scanner, so I scan it as more than one image and stitch the parts together to create a single image of the original.
As long as I can remember, GIMP has been my tool of choice, because it has all of the functionality required to do everything I want.

- It allows scanning directly into the package
- It allows the size of images to be extended to make room for a second image
- It supports layers and transparency so two images can be aligned on top of each other
- It allows export in formats that I desire

However every time it takes hours and hours as I try the obvious way to do each next step, fall into a hole and google for some time to find a solution given (often patronisingly) to some other poor person who had the same problem.  It is just one stumble after another, and for all of the hundreds of hours I have used it over the years, the logic is so far from standard mac/windows GUI that it has not sunk in at all.

Some aspects of the Gimp GUI have improved over the years, but the logic of selecting parts of images and moving them about always eludes me and takes forever to rediscover.  "No I would never want to select an area and then move the boundary of the area instead of the pixels of the area!!!"

Whenever I look for alternatives, it is apparent that most apps strive to be one or more of

- a tool for artists to paint/draw pictures
- a tool to "correct" photos
- a tool to manage a photograph collection.

but they don't do the fundamental swiss army knife image manipulations:

- get multiple images in from file or scanner,
- fix geometry to match them up,
- export image

workflow very well, or like Gimp (and imageMagick) they involve a substantial learning curve to master non-standard commands

So my question is, "Is there a package which has a standard macPaint/Microsoft Paint style GUI which supports multiple layers, transparency, image resizing, rotation and input from SANE scanning drivers, and is not cluttered by vast amounts of functionality which impede this basic workflow?"

Comment: Try asking on [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Panorama apps such as Hugin can also be [used to stitch scans](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml).